# reportes RDLC en c#

Tags: c#, reportviewer

Necesito agregar dos reportes RDLC en un solo control de ReportViewer en puro código, alguien sabe como hacerlo, ya que después genero un PDF y quiero que tenga los dos reportes ese PDF, lo tengo ahorita con solo un RDLC :

```
ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = Path.Combine(directorioPrincipal, @"xxxx.rdlc");
viewer.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
viewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(lista);
viewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(repdata);
viewer.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

No puede asignar dos `.rdlc` en un mismo ReportViewer

Pero si podrias crear un tercer .rdlc y usar los otros dos dentro de un subreporte

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui

[SSRS Series Part II: Working with Subreports, DrillDown Reports, Expressions and Custom codes, Databars, Indicators, Custom Sorting and Paging and many more](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/195017/SSRS-Series-Part-II-Working-with-Subreports-DrillD)

explica con mayor detalle el tema de subreportes.

**>>como hago para que cada .rdlc pertenezca a una hoja cada uno?**

Podrias definir un page break entre los subreportes para que cada uno aparezca en diferentes páginas

[How to: Set Page Breaks (Visual Studio Report Designer)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251733(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Hola Leandro, me parece buena idea lo que me dices, pero  como hago para que cada .rdlc pertenezca a una hoja cada uno?, esto es para cuando genere mi pdf tenga dos hojas

Comment: Entiendo que puedes definir un page break en el reporte, de esta forma saltara de pagina luego de terminado uno de los reportes